# How to change the vibration strength in Android?

Tags: java, android, vibration

I want to create an app where you can test the **vibration**, including the **strength** and in the normal code you can only set the length of the vibration in milliseconds.
The problem is I can't find any code that can influence the strength of the vibration motor.

I have tried:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(1000);
```

It works but as I said, only the milliseconds are adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread helps you: (Answer 1)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690376/reduce-notification-vibration-intensity-to-zero-in-android-programatically#:~:text=Go%20to%20Setting,Call%2C%20Notification%2C%20and%20Haptic%20Feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690376/reduce-notification-vibration-intensity-to-zero-in-android-programatically#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Setting,Call%2C%20Notification%2C%20and%20Haptic%20Feedback)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can influence the strength of the vibration motor as per your need. But yes you can play with `VibrationEffect` which have a different set of different effect.

[image]