# Vibrator intensity is too soft

Tags: android, vibration

I use "vibrator.vibrate(2000);" for vibration and it vibrates, but the intensity is very soft.
I know that my phone is able to vibrate much stronger because when receiving a call or notification it vibrates correctly.
Why is the function vibrate() so week?
Thanks

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(4000);
```

The phone vibrates really strong when receiving a text or a notification, though

Answer (score 2):

You can not increase further vibration intensity. So to get better feel you can use     `public void vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)`  instead of `vibrator.vibrate(2000);`

here the patter is (from the api reference)

> Pass in an array of ints that are the durations for which to turn on
>   or off the vibrator in milliseconds. The first value indicates the
>   number of milliseconds to wait before turning the vibrator on. The
>   next value indicates the number of milliseconds for which to keep the
>   vibrator on before turning it off. Subsequent values alternate between
>   durations in milliseconds to turn the vibrator off or to turn the
>   vibrator on.

so you can try different patterns to get a better feel. for example

```
final long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500, 500, 200 };
vibrator.vibrate(pattern , 0);
```

you can create your own pattern to check.

Comment: yes I knew that, thanks, but the problem is that it vibrates correctly but VERY SOFT, or at least, much softer than when receiving a call or a notification.

Comment: as i mentioned you can not increase the intensity more.. the softness may be handset dependent

Answer (score 2):

In most phones, the vibration is caused (quite crudely) by a minature vibration motor which has an offset weight on the shaft. Such that, when the motor is activated and the shaft spins, the offset weight causes the motor, and whatever it is attached to, to vibrate. There is no control other than the duration for which power is applied to the motor.

[image: Typical Miniature Vibration Motor]

Though this wouldn't seem to explain why call receipt or notification manages to produce a stronger vibration than the one you get yourself through the API function.  So perhaps I should have made this a comment rather than an answer? (But I couldn't see how to get the picture in a comment)

Comment: Thanks for the information. It would be great if you guys test this issue too. So, we know 100% if it is just me. It is as simple as I show in the question. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess as I've never used the vibrator, but perhaps try increasing the value you're passing to the function?

Comment: That value is just the milliseconds on, increasing that value has no effect on intensity

Answer (score 0):

On my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3) the intensity of the vibrator is triggered by the system wide setting found in menu item

`phone settings > My device > Sound > Vibration intensity`

Here, you can adjust the vibration intensity for `Incoming call`, `Notification` and `Haptic feedback`. The setting of `Notification` influences the intensity of the vibration you cause with your implementation. Setting that value to zero leads to the effect that your phone does not vibrate at all with your code.

Comment: And how can I change those intensities by code? I haven't found any Samsung Api to do that.

Comment: It does not seem to be possible to change it with the available API. Please take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888043/controlling-vibration-intensity-in-android-phones-is-it-possible?rq=1) and at the Android documentation  [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html).