# How can I control the amplitude/strength of vibration with the web Vibration API?

Tags: javascript, waveform, vibration

Our web app uses [the Vibrate API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API) for a subtle button press effect:

```js
window.navigator.vibrate(5);
```

But on my new phone, it feels less subtle, and more like my phone is trying to jump out of my hand. The problem is that the `window.navigator.vibrate` API does not let me set the amplitude/strength of the vibration; it only lets me set the duration.

With Android's `VibrationEffect`, [you can set the "amplitude"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect). With iOS's Core Haptics, [you can set "intensity" and "sharpness"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics/updating_continuous_and_transient_haptic_parameters_in_real_time).

**How can I set the amplitude/strength/sharpness/intensity of a vibration using the web Vibrate API?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [controlling vibration intensity in android phones? is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888043/controlling-vibration-intensity-in-android-phones-is-it-possible)

Comment: @Justinas no, that question is about the native Android APIs - I'm talking about the web Vibration API

Comment: Taking a look at [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#dom-navigator-vibrate) there's nothing that appears to allow you to control the strength of the vibrations!

Comment: This is obviously a hack but if nothing else works for you, you might want to give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417997/12057512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#dom-navigator-vibrate) there's nothing that appears to allow you to control anything more than the pattern of vibrations.

From the spec W3C

```
typedef (unsigned long or sequence<unsigned long>) VibratePattern;

partial interface Navigator {
    boolean vibrate (VibratePattern pattern);
};
```

> The vibrate() method steps are to run the processing vibration patterns algorithm. A vibration pattern is represented by a VibratePattern object.

Comment: As it stands, I will be accepting this answer, as I think it's the technically correct one. But I'll leave this up for a few days to see if anyone knows of any bleeding-edge additions. Emil's "interleave on/off" hack is also interesting.